# How to join filtered cells into one cell, if it should be filtered by specified value in other cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So, I have two tables. One has like an order number, the other has details to the order. The datails are added into different rows, each row has order number.
Smth like:
Main Sheet >> Date, Order number, Order details;
Order-log Sheet >> Date Order Number, Detail

There should be a list of details in the Order details cell.

`=Arrayformula(if(IsBlank(C2:C),"add order number",JOIN(", ", filter('Order-log'!F:F,NOT(ISBLANK('Order-log'!F:F)),'Order-log'!C:C=C2))))`

The problem with my arrayformula is with the second filter criteria, it is not changing. How to modify it?

Comment: Please share a spreadsheet with sample data and desired effect.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [how-to-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Index-Match to join the two tables. For e.g.

1. Table1 has rows for order details and one column is Order Number(Col B)
2. Table2 has a unique row for each order, Col H is the order number.
3. the details in Column I will get appended as a column to the first table, from the row where the value in col B matches the value in Col H.

=ArrayFormula(INDEX(I$6:I$9,MATCH($B6,$H$6:$H$9,0)))

Here is a link to the sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w6bZMWxEp5Qvhy_NjcG_kH8Hpq3Mc7v0XByDam1-wCQ/edit?usp=sharing

Khalid